# semanticUI issue with using Dropdown or Select - Unknown prop `control` on <select> tag

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Created following container in react.js using semanticUI (react.SemanticUI)
When I use this in code I get the following warning: 
Warning: Unknown prop `control` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

I am unable to figure out why using as='select' is giving this error. If I remove the as='select', I get a different error saying I cannot have an array inside

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Container, Form, Select } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const AnswerOptionYesNoSelect = ({ Id, Value, onAnswerChanged }) => (
  <Container>
    <Form.Select as="select" required name={Id} defaultValue={Value} onChange={onAnswerChanged} placeholder="Select Options">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Oklahoma">OK</option>
      <option value="Texas">TX</option>
    </Form.Select>
  </Container>
);

AnswerOptionYesNoSelect.propTypes = {
  Id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  Value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onAnswerChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default AnswerOptionYesNoSelect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Form.Select` with

```js
<Form.Field
    control='select'
    required name={Id}
    defaultValue={Value}
    onChange={onAnswerChanged}
    placeholder="Select Options"
>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Oklahoma">OK</option>
  <option value="Texas">TX</option>
</Form.Field>
```